# Restriction of Maclaurin series of $\ln(x+1)$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know that, $$\ln(x+1) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty(-1)^n\dfrac{ x^{n+1}}{n+1} \forall x \in (-1, 1]$$

My question is, why is there restriction on the value of $x$? If that's the case then how can we find value of $\ln(4)$ or say $\ln(5)?$

I don't understand this restriction. Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: The series will not converge if you substitute an $x$ which is larger than $1$.

Comment: @Gary So how can we find say $\ln(3), \ln(5)$ etc.? Can't we find using the expansion formula of $\ln(x+1)$?

Comment: For example, $$
\log x = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2n + 1}}\left( {\frac{{x - 1}}{{x + 1}}} \right)^{2n + 1} } 
$$ converges for all $x>0$. You can also use tricks like $\log 3 = \log (1 + 1) + \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{2}} \right)$, and apply the series for $\log(1+x)$ with $x=1$ and $x=1/2$ separately.

Comment: You can also use $\ln (x+1)=-\ln (-\frac{x}{x+1}+1)$, and the fact that $-1<-\frac{x}{x+1} <0$ for $x>1$. For example $\ln 5=-\ln (-\frac{4}{5}+1)$ and use your series now.